# locals not working within variables in Terraform

Tags: terraform

```
locals {
  cool_style = {
    palette = "cool"
    type    = "solid"
    width   = "normal"
  }
  orange_style = {
    palette = "orange"
    type    = "solid"
    width   = "normal"
  }
}

variable "query_timeseries" {
  default = [
    {
      q     = "avg:xx.xxxx{xxx:xx}"
      type  = "bars"
      style = local.cool_style
    },
    {
      q     = "avg:xx.xxxx{xxx:xx}"
      type  = "bars"
      style = local.orange_style
    }
}
```

Unable to re-use the declared variable in .tf file

[image]

**What I need?:**

I need to declare a variable by injecting an existing variable in it

Comment: You're using them the wrong way around. Variables can't include interpolation so if you want interpolation then they should be a local. In your case if the `cool_style` and `orange_style` are meant to be unconfigurable (and so not changeable by the caller of the code) then it should all be locals.

Comment: I did locals.cool_style and it results the same

Comment: No. The point is that your `query_timeseries` should be a local. Currently you have it as a variable but variables cannot contain interpolation as the error message is telling you.

Comment: yea I get it; btw, it is not allowing me to declare `query_timeseries` as locals. Is there anyway to declare `cool_style ` & `orange_style` and re-use it as a variable in variables.tf?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question really.

Comment: Probably I will modify the question if I get the answer :)

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. If you end up with a follow up question then you should raise a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the `variable` to a `local` so it can use the other local variables is the correct solution. Using terraform 0.12.x the following works as expected as seen by the `terraform apply`.

```hcl
locals {
  cool_style = {
    palette = "cool"
    type    = "solid"
    width   = "normal"
  }
  orange_style = {
    palette = "orange"
    type    = "solid"
    width   = "normal"
  }
  query_timeseries = [
    {
      q     = "avg:xx.xxxx{xxx:xx}"
      type  = "bars"
      style = local.cool_style
    },
    {
      q     = "avg:xx.xxxx{xxx:xx}"
      type  = "bars"
      style = local.orange_style
    }
  ]
}

output "query_timeseries" {
  value = local.query_timeseries
}
```

```sh
$ terraform init
$ terraform apply
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

query_timeseries = [
  {
    "q" = "avg:xx.xxxx{xxx:xx}"
    "style" = {
      "palette" = "cool"
      "type" = "solid"
      "width" = "normal"
    }
    "type" = "bars"
  },
  {
    "q" = "avg:xx.xxxx{xxx:xx}"
    "style" = {
      "palette" = "orange"
      "type" = "solid"
      "width" = "normal"
    }
    "type" = "bars"
  },
]
```